# Fedora 32/33 - Remove password strength enforcement

Tags: fedora, passwd

Fedora 32/33 wont let me select a short password for root and user. In this case i want to allow it, but i cannot do so:

```
❯ sudo passwd
Changing password for user root.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters
Retype new password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

So i tried to understand the 2 files setting up those settings, but im lost.

```
❯ cat /etc/pam.d/password-auth
# Generated by authselect 
# Do not modify this file manually.

auth        required                                     pam_env.so
auth        required                                     pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient                                   pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        sufficient                                   pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth        required                                     pam_deny.so

account     required                                     pam_unix.so
account     sufficient                                   pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient                                   pam_usertype.so issystem
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required                                     pam_permit.so

password    requisite                                    pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only
password    sufficient                                   pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient                                   pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required                                     pam_deny.so

session     optional                                     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required                                     pam_limits.so
-session    optional                                     pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore]                   pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required                                     pam_unix.so
session     optional                                     pam_sss.so
```

and

```
❯ cat /etc/pam.d/passwd
#%PAM-1.0
# This tool only uses the password stack.
password   substack system-auth
-password   optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so use_authtok
password   substack postlogin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Fedora 32, the password quality configuration files are `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` and `/etc/security/pwquality.conf.d/*`

For example, minimum password length:

```
# Configuration for systemwide password quality limits
# Defaults:
#
# Minimum acceptable size for the new password (plus one if
# credits are not disabled which is the default). (See pam_cracklib manual.)
# Cannot be set to lower value than 6.
# minlen = 8
```

The relevant man pages are `pwquality.conf(5)` and `pam_pwquality(5)`.

Comment: Hi  @fpmurphy, by chaning /etc/security/pwquality.conf i do not get "BAD PASSWORD" anylonger but i still get "passwd: Authentication token manipulation error". This in all cases: as user, sudo, or as root.

Comment: @user654789384.  That is a different issue, I think. Is SELinux enabled?   What runlevel are you at?

Comment: Multiuser-Target. Im not super experienced with Linux, just using it. So i dont know if SELinux is enabled, default Fedora32 install with then release upgrade to 33.

Comment: What is the output of `getenforce`?

Comment: Ok sorry i have it, thank you very much: solution: temp disable Selinux, change root and user passwd, reenable selinux: (A) sudo setenforce 0 (B) passwd <user> (C) sudo setenforce 1

Comment: @user654789384.   If that is the case, you have something wrong with your SELinux context on either `/etc/passwd` or more likely `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115540/discussion-between-user654789384-and-fpmurphy).